# "=" is invisible in nano editor (wsl)

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nano

The problem is simple: `=` is invisible in WSL's `nano` and I don't think this should be happening:

- ```
  #! /usr/bin/bash
  STRING="e"
  echo "$STRING"
  ```

  [image: screenshot]

Is there some way to turn this off?

Comment: Which Linux distribution on WSL? I can't make it happen on Ubuntu WSL.

Comment: And which terminal?

Comment: Doesn't do it in WSL2 Debian. What happens if you start nano like this `nano -Ynone`?

Comment: What is your locale? See this question - https://superuser.com/questions/1522154/nano-displays-spaces-instead-of-some-symbols

Comment: @harrymc i am indeed using Ubuntu WSL

Comment: Mine doesn't do that. Perhaps you should uninstall and reinstall WSL to restore the defaults.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that works, but the syntax highlighting is gone, and I don't want that.

Comment: It looks to me like you have an unfortunate combination of console background & foreground color scheme, locale setting, and nano syntax highlight color scheme. You can alter all of these things, as Linux is configurable by design. You can choose which colors nano uses for highlighting different things in code by editing a `nanorc` file and here is an article about that http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/nanorc.5.html

Comment: First thing I do when installing any Linux distro is get rid of all those goddam console color schemes. Plain black on white for me. Everywhere. Some default schemes make my eyes bleed.